# Detect all clicks inside Angular app for all components, even with stopPropagation() used

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, click, stoppropagation

This code is almost nicely used to track all clicks inside the Angular application on the page:

```
  @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
  handleDocumentClicks(target) {
    console.log('A click happened. This is displayed for all links but unfortunately not for Modify link because its handleModifyClick contains event.stopPropagation()');
    console.log(target);
    //do some logic here
  }
```

Unfortunately, for some links inside child components such as

**list.component.html**

```
<a href="javascript:;" (click)="handleModifyClick($event)">Modify</a>
```

**list.component.ts**

```
  handleModifyClick(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // some more ts logic comes here
  }
```

`handleDocumentClicks` is not triggered, when we click on Modify link, because `handleModifyClick` function contains `stopPropagation()` method.

Is there a smart way to track all document clicks without changing the code inside child components, without removing `stopPropagation()` methods inside all child components?

Comment: Adding a top-level `div` with a higher z index and a transparent background may work. That way all the clicks pass through your div.

Comment: @Eldar could you please post you solution? If you suggest to add a div with a higher z-index and set the height as 100vh or so to cover everything and probably to set position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0 and as you suggested background: transparent;  then the links are not clickable. If you set pointer-events: none; to the div to make the links clickable, then again the Modify link is not tracked on click. So, could you please explain your solution if it exists? Thank you.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eezigo?file=src/overlay/overlay.component.ts) works for you. It became very different from the way I described above. It still uses an overlay div but not as a parent. And it forwards click events but this might break many things.